# display byte[] array variable in textbox (as is)

Tags: c#, arrays

Maybe already Asked Question, but how much I look I didnt find or didnt convert how I wish. Sorry if Question repeating (please show me link if is).

I am getting some info in byte array and when debugging I see it in decimal form. How to show this byte array like it is in textblock or label?

I dont want some HEX form, just pure decimal byte array :)

Any question please ask. Thanks for help!

Comment: Google. This might work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166757/conversion-of-byte-array-containing-hex-values-to-decimal-values

Comment: Neither textblock nor label show "pure decimal byte arrays". You need to convert it to string first, somehow. What are you trying to get? A list of decimal numbers separated by commas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [String.Join](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join)

```
textBox1.Text = String.Join(",", buf);
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this would fit:

```
using System.Text;
StringBuilder sb = "";
foreach (byte b in byteArray)
{
    sb.AppendLine(b);
}
Label.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Regards.

Comment: @RonBeyer Oh, you're right, I totally forgot that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

C# byte stores 8bits (0-255) it is shown to you as something more readable. 
It is not showing you a decimal number, it is showing you a c# byte, a number from 0 to 255.

references :
[C# - Reading bytes, what are they and what's going on.  I expect binary values, not decimal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295230/c-sharp-reading-bytes-what-are-they-and-whats-going-on-i-expect-binary-val)